# Mypy + FastAPI response_model

Tags: python, typing, mypy, fastapi

I've been tasked with handling the update from Mypy 0.770 to 0.870 in our FastAPI project, and this has produced an error that I can't quite wrap my head around. My endpoint can return two different models based on some condition, and this was denoted as follows the endpont decorator:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=Union[Model1, Model2])
```

Mypy 0.870 now complains about this, stating that

```
Argument "response_model" to "get" of "APIRouter" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Optional[Type[Any]]"
```

Setting it to single types, such as `Model1` or even `str` removes the error. `Any` however, does *not* work.

Now, looking into the `get` method, I see that the `response_model` argument is typed as `Type[Any]`, which I assume must be a pointer.

How I can define non-simple return models for my API, and make Mypy happy?

edit: I tried to reproduce the problem in a smaller frame, but couldn't. The following code works fine:

```
from typing import Any, Type, Union


def test1(var, response_model: Type[Any]):
    print(f"Accepted Type[Any], {var}")

def test2(var, response_model: Union[dict, set]):
    print(f"Accepted Union, {var}")

def main():
    test1('test1', response_model=Union[dict, set])
    test2('test2', response_model=Union[dict, set])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you figured this out @oyblix?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( I ended up Using MyPy's `type: ignore` feature, but as this problem seemingly arose after a mypy (or FastAPI, can't remember) update, it might just be a fixable incompatibility issue. Feel free to report an issue to FastAPI - I don't recall doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue introduced in newer versions of mypy.
There is an open issue on Github about this topic:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2279

In the discussion they provide the following workarounds:

- Using a different approach to create a type alias:

  `NewModel = TypeVar('NewModel',Model1,Model2)`
- Creating a new Pydantic Model :

  ```
  class NewModel(BaseModel):
       __root__: Union[Model1, Model2]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`Type[]` of something means a not instantiated class of this type, while `Model1` here will mean an instance of a `Model1` class or an instance of anything that inherits from `Model1`.

Nonetheless, the error message is enigmatic.

What `python -v` are you using? Typing is a new thing in a python world and things might change between python versions as well. If you bumped `mypy` version it might be good to upgrade `python` as well as they go together.

Also, what `fastapi` version are you using? I'd try bump it to the latest, `0.55.1`, as well. Tiangolo himself wrote they have had a bug with typing

[source](https://gitter.im/tiangolo/fastapi?at=5cfd2685d4e3840c6959d1f3)

Comment: We're using FastApi 0.52.0 and python 3.8.3. I tried updating to FastApi 0.55.1, but that didn't seem to help :/